# How do you resolve undefined reference errors from linking using libcurl?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, static, libcurl

I'm trying to compile a program with static linking so I don't have to distribute it with 30 .dlls, but `-static` is giving me a whole load of undefined reference errors.

I'm running

```
$ gcc curlgetter2BAK.cpp -lcurl -static -o a.out
```

which gives me an atrociously huge pile of undefine reference errors that I'm unsure as to the source of.

Comment: You need to figure out which library provides the symbols mentioned in the underfined reference errors and make sure they're in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Showing the errors usually helps in determining the source

Comment: If your libcurl is configured to use OpenSSL, then you have to build it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-static` is not a magic keyword, you need to have static versions (`.a` files) of all those 30 "dlls" *and their dependencies*.